# WSO2 Developer Studio Proxy List

Tags: wso2

I am working through the ["Cloud to RDBMS" example](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/cloud-to-rdbms-using-wso2-esb/) using wso2 developer studio.

At the bottom it says:

> "Finally, to try the service, go to the proxy list and click try it
>   under Salesforce proxy."

I'm new with Developer Studio and cannot find a "proxy list" anywhere.

Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finally, to try the service, go to the proxy list and click try it under Salesforce proxy.

It is not telling you to click "try it" on the developer studio. It is telling you to login to ESB management console (https://localhost:9443/carbon) and click "List" under "Services" from the main menu as shown below.

[image]

And click "Try this service" of the relevant proxy service to go to the "Try it" tool.

[image]

So you have to first have to deploy the proxy in ESB and try above steps. [This article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/06/develop-and-deploy-esb-artifacts-using-wso2-developer-studio/) would be useful for you to start with.